# Custom Path for locating a specific file in specific folder c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I want to look up at the database's file in the specific folder and what I did before is like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Fuhans's Folder/Project/SIA - Point of Sales/SIA - Point of Sales/Assets/Database/db1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
```

and I am thinking that is there a shortcut way to look up the database's file, instead of writing a specific folder?

and I came up with:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=../Assets/Database/db1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
```

But, when I changed it into like the second one, the error message appear like below:

[image]

My question is: Is there a way to delete the `bin` location path, but still doing the look up the database's file like the second one?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for someone who votes up for this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another `../` in front of the relative path:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=../../Assets/Database/db1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid to use absolute paths in your connection string and relative paths (with `..` are pretty easy to be broken when you deploy).

[In ASP.NET to use a relative](http://forums.asp.net/t/1142512.aspx?How%20would%20I%20define%20a%20relative%20path%20for%20an%20Access%20DB%20connection%20string%20) path you may use `|DataDirectory|db1.accdb`, in WinForms it's not available but that *constants* are resolved using Application Domain properties. Simply set your base bath inside your main() method:

```
AppDomain.Current.SetData("RootFolder",
    @"D:\Fuhans's Folder\Project\SIA - Point of Sales\SIA - Point of Sales");
```

And your connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|RootFolder|Assets/Database/db1.accdb;
```

Why you should use an absolute path instead of a relative one? Because it won't be affected by working directory and it's easier to add multiple constants:

```
AppDomain.Current.SetData("Bin",
    Application.StartupPath);
AppDomain.Current.SetData("AppData",
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

Second option will work much better with UAC (where program's folder may not be writeable at all). Also note that path is still *navigable* because it'll be normalized.

Assuming your compiling to bin/debug in your development environment:

```
Data Source=|Bin|../../Assets/Database/db1.accdb
```

Assuming your application will be deployed and it'll work on data folder (not program folder):

```
Data Source=|AppData|Assets/Database/db1.accdb
```

Straight and easy.

Comment: But, that is makes the application have to installed on that particular folders right sir @Adriano Repetti? What happens if the user change the folders into something else that is not match to the set string? and with "easy to be broken", with what did you refer to sir? and how is that possible? Thank you

Comment: @UnknownUser of course path should not be hard-coded! Easy to be broken because relative path will be affected by working directory, if you declare `RootFolder` to be `Application.StartupPath` then path in connection string will always be rooted from executable path. Moreover note you can still combine then if you're compiling into `root\debug\release`  your **absolute** path will be `|RootFolder|..\..\assets\db1.accdb`. Note that you can define **multiple constants** (for example for an `AppData` directory), with UAC program folder may not be writeable...

Comment: +1 for your clear explanation sir @Adriano Repetti. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Clearly a better answer than mine! For the sake of other programmers looking for a solution for similar issues, you should accept this one.

Comment: @hantoun I don't think so! Accepted answer is what user found to be useful in his case, if he doesn't need anything more complicate then simply add "../" is as good as this (and much shorter). In future, programmers that will find this useful...may vote up.

Comment: I do admit it your solution was more secure and useful, +1 for your solution sir hantoun and Adriano Repetti (it cannot be easy to be broken as sir Adriano Repetti said), but for the main reason that I want to fast as possible without worrying about (only) for this one, I chose sir hantoun solution. But, of course, after the project that I am doing done and being release (give it to my requester (customer) ), I will read and trying to understand more about your solution sir Adriano Repetti and use it for the future.